# How to Calculate bfOffBits

Tags: c, bitmap, byte

I'm attempting to read and open a BMP file manually with C, and after reading the BMP specs and learning about how these files work, the header has definitions for the bytes that equal things like `bfOffBits` and `biWidth`. So for example the `bfOffBits` is equal to 4 bytes which are '8A 04 00 00' in my testing bitmap. How exactly do I get from here to the decimal equivalent for the offset data of the image?

I am very, very new to C so the concepts of how the language works is very different to me considering that the main language I work in is PHP, so go easy on me :)

Currently, I am using this function in C which feels completely wrong but was sort of working for some offset values and not other offset values

```
int calculateBytes(int bytes[4]) {
    int Value = bytes[0];
    if (bytes[1] > 0) {
        if (bytes[0] == 0) {
            Value = 256;
        }
        Value = Value * bytes[1];
    }
    if (bytes[2] > 0) {
        if (bytes[1] == 0) {
            if (bytes[0] == 0) {
                Value = 256;
            }
            Value = Value * 256;
        }
        Value = Value * bytes[2];
    }
    if (bytes[3] > 0) {
        if (bytes[2] == 0) {
            if (bytes[1] == 0) {
                if (bytes[0] == 0) {
                    Value = 256;
                }
                Value = Value * 256;
            }
            Value = Value * 256;
        }
        Value = Value * bytes[3];
    }
    return Value;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it simply like that:

```
char bytes[] = {0x8A, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00};
int* p_int = (int*)bytes; // Unsafe version ,doesn't take into account endianness
int num2 = bytes[0] | ( (int)bytes[1] << 8 ) | ( (int)bytes[2] << 16 ) | ( (int)bytes[3] << 24 ); // Safe version
printf("%d %d\n", *p_int, num2);
```

So your function would look like this:

```
int calculateBytes(int bytes[4]) {
    int num = bytes[0]
              | ( (int)bytes[1] << 8 )
              | ( (int)bytes[2] << 16 )
              | ( (int)bytes[3] << 24 );
    return num;
}
```

Comment: Ah this worked! And very easy to understand, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

the posted value '8A 04 00 00'  looks like 'little Endian'.

Is the architecture your using 'little Endian'.  if so, just read the value into an int.  Otherwise,  reverse the order of the 4 bytes.

Then printf the resulting value with something like: printf(" offset: %d\n", myInt );

---

a simple way to convert 'little Endian' to 'big Endian' on a 32 bit architecture.

```
int convert( char *pBytes )
{
    int result = 0;
    result = pBytes[3];
    result <<= 8;
    result += pBytes[2];
    result <<= 8;
    result += pBytes[1];
    result <<= 8;
    result += pBytes[0];
    return( result );
} // end function: convert
```

Comment: Thanks! I also understand this one, but looks like you were one minute too short